# Пример фильтрации поиска на react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Нужна помощь в объяснении подобного поиска (не обязательно код, а по шагам, как лучше сделать). Без каких-либо готовых решений/плагинов

После ввода данных в поля, нажимаем на кнопку "применить" и введенные данные отображаются через запятую в поиске наверху:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пример кода
https://codesandbox.io/s/forms-tutorial-zuy1f

Сложно понять как реализовать на redux:

1. Должны ли быть у reducer'а фильтра начальные состояния с пустыми значениями?
2. Как лучше отследить изменения в текстовых полях

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно создать action для каждого инпута, если планируется, что все эти инпуты - это все инпуты с такой бизнес-логикой во всем приложении. Ловишь события onKeyDown и отправляешь в redux стейт, а из стейта читаешь данные в value - всё будет обновляться. Когда создаешь store указываешь все значения пустой строкой, чтобы не было ошибки в React компоненте. Можно сделать без локального стейта компонента. К кнопке привязываешь функцию onClick, которая просто заменит location.href; Через запятую это функция [1,2,3].join();

```js
export default ({setДиагональ, диагональ и т.д.}) => {
  <input onKeyDown={setДиагональ} value={диагональ}> и т.д.
}
```

Применить

```js
const apply = () => [диагональ, тип, вес, производитель].join()
```